# Apply SequenceMatcher to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and Python in general, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this simple question. I have a large dataframe `m` with several million rows and seven columns, including an `ITEM_NAME_x` and `ITEM_NAME_y`. I want to compare `ITEM_NAME_x` and `ITEM_NAME_y` using `SequenceMatcher.ratio()`, and add a new column to the dataframe with the result.

I've tried to come at this several ways, but keep running into errors:

```
>>> m.apply(SequenceMatcher(None, str(m.ITEM_NAME_x), str(m.ITEM_NAME_y)).ratio(), axis=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4416, in apply
return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4491, in _apply_standard
raise e
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4480, in _apply_standard
results[i] = func(v)
TypeError: ("'float' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Could someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply a function, not a float which expression `SequenceMatcher(None, str(m.ITEM_NAME_x), str(m.ITEM_NAME_y)).ratio()` is.

Working demo (a draft):

```
import difflib
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

def apply_sm(s, c1, c2): 
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s[c1], s[c2]).ratio()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: 'one'}, 'B': {1: 'two'}})
print df.apply(partial(apply_sm, c1='A', c2='B'), axis=1)
```

output:

```
1    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way that I could add the SequenceMatcher results as a new column in the existing dataframe? Otherwise I would have to merge the results back in.

Comment: @user1272739 assign with `df['sm'] = df.apply(...)`

Comment: I tried that code but it throws me an error: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. What could be wrong?